# Rails - Devise - User Sign In Streak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

im trying to keep count of a users sign in streak (days) with devise.

added a new column time_since_sign_in integer to user table.

overriding devise sessions controller

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }
```

added this which i thought would update attr before sign in

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    current_user.update_sign_in_streak
    # even if i comment out super, last_sign_in_at still gets updated
    super
  end
end
```

added to user model

```
def update_sign_in_streak
  # binding.pry
  # at this point last_sign_in_at always updated
  time_since_sign_in = Time.now - last_sign_in_at
  if time_since_sign_in.between?(1.day, 2.day)
    increment! :sign_in_streak
  elsif time_since_sign_in > 2.day
    sign_in_streak = 0
    save
  end
end
```

so apparently devise has this hook, which updates the tracking fields. but why does it get called before create successful? any ideas on how i can get this working?

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user :except => :fetch do |record, warden, options|
  if record.respond_to?(:update_tracked_fields!) && warden.authenticated?(options[:scope]) && !warden.request.env['devise.skip_trackable']
    record.update_tracked_fields!(warden.request)
  end
end
```

Comment: i don't understand you. what exactly is not working?

Comment: sorry. so if i stop at binding.pry under update_sign_in_streak, the last_sign_in_at has already been updated by the warden callback

Comment: so the time_since_sign_in variable i set will always be 0 / close to it

Answer (score 0):

i figured out a bad hack, but if anyone has a better answer please let me know

(btw the problem again is that the last_sign_in_at attr gets updated in a prepend_before_filter before the create action, so I dont ever have access to the last_sign_in_at value)

forked devise!

trackable model

```
def update_tracked_fields!(request)
  update_sign_in_streak

  # ...
end

def update_sign_in_streak
  time_since_sign_in = Time.now - self.last_sign_in_at
  if time_since_sign_in.between?(1.day, 2.day)
    self.sign_in_streak += 1
  elsif time_since_sign_in > 2.day
    self.sign_in_streak = 1
  end
end
```